# Find on source page <script> line

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Could someone please assist me in solving following:

I have to test does source code of page contains following line:

```
<script>dataLayer.push({'login':'not logged in','site-language':'es','article-type':'2','section1':'error page','section2':'error page > access denied'});</script>
```

Actually I am looking for **access denied** or **error page > access denied** if exist on that page and get stuck when found page source

```
 driver.navigate().to(BaseTest.config("url") + "/es/pronosticos");
   String link = driver.getPageSource();
```

Which has to be next step to check if above line exist on current page?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is basic `String` manipulation.

You can perform operations like `matches()` or `contains()` methods on `String`.

Example:

```
driver.navigate().to(BaseTest.config("url") + "/es/pronosticos");
String link = driver.getPageSource();
String script = "<script>dataLayer.push({'login':'not logged in','site-language':'es','article-type':'2','section1':'error page','section2':'error page > access denied'});</script>";

if (link.contains(script)) System.out.println("Site contains script");
else System.out.println("Site does NOT contain script");
```

The other approach would be trying to find `<script`> element via `WebDriver`

```
try {
    WebElement script = driver.findElement(By.tagName("script"));
    String scriptText = script.getText(); //returns the text of <script> tag
    if (scriptText.contains("access denied")) System.out.println("Access Denied!");
    else System.out.println("Access granted");
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println("Script does NOT exist!");
}
```

Comment: Laskowski Thanks, second approach is perfect!